# ASP.Net MVC null reference exception with TextArea name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a TextArea html helper method I'm calling in a foreach loop.  Basically, when I initially load the View it works fine, but when i reload the View and load postback data, the same TextArea throws a NullReferenceException and yet the variable I'm using in the TextArea as the name of the TextArea is not null.  I've attached a picture below for demonstration:

[image]

Sorry if it's difficult to see, the blue arrow below is pointing to the variable used to name the TextArea.  Again, it works on initial load, but it errors out on postback when the page is reloaded.  I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: what is the test variable inside Html.TextArea? Did you mean the string "test"?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes the test variable is of type string, in the image above it is equal to "2" as the blue arrow shows.  I'm using it as the name of the TextArea. I'm displaying multiple entities from a DB in this view and am using their unique IDs as names for their respective TextAreas, as you may or may not be able to tell from the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://forums.asp.net/p/1396019/3006051.aspx) seemed to provide the solution.  Turns out I was not setting the model value after adding errors to the model state, so it was searching for the model values to place back into the TextArea, they were null of course, hence the error.  Very obscure error in my opinion.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267209/null-reference-exception-and-the-operator) StackOverflow post was also very enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom validation in your application?  If so, this is a known issue in MVC 1 (fixed for MVC 2).  See http://forums.asp.net/p/1377232/2908610.aspx for more context and a workaround.